# ggplot - Reorder Bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Dear Members of the Coding Community,

As the title of my query suggests I'd like to **change the order of the bars** in the following plot

*(i.e. having both "immediate" bars appear before the "delayed" ones)* :

```
ggplot(propho.effect.frame, aes(session, fit, color=modality, fill=modality)) + geom_bar(stat='identity',position="dodge") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se), width=0.4, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + theme_bw(base_size=12) + labs(y="score", title="Phonological Production Task")
```

[image]

```
## INITIAL DATAFRAME ##############################################

PID   session group list modality    stim score
1  AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM FAHRRAD     0
2  AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM    BUCH     1
3  AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM   SCHAF     0
4  AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM   STUHL     0
5  AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM    AFFE     0
6  AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM   KERZE     0
7  AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM  KIRCHE     0
8  AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM   NAGEL     0
9  AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM  PFANNE     0
10 AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM   KLEID     0
11 AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM    HAHN     0
12 AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM    KAMM     0
13 AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM    PILZ     1
14 AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM   BIRNE     0
15 AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM   VOGEL     0
16 AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM  SCHALE     0
17 AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM   PFEIL     0
18 AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM TROMMEL     0
19 AL201 immediate     A    X      OLM  LEITER     0
20 AL201 immediate     A    Y     NOLM    KORB     0
> 

## propho.effect.frame (cf. ggplot code) ##########################

modality   session       fit         se     lower     upper
1     NOLM   delayed 0.3525117 0.08066153 0.2140540 0.5211437
2      OLM   delayed 0.6472552 0.07339121 0.4942436 0.7750446
3     NOLM immediate 0.3271910 0.07654911 0.1974255 0.4901584
4      OLM immediate 0.5659339 0.07947359 0.4088293 0.7108196
```

After trying to apply the suggestions of similar queries on the forum without success (e.g. `propho$session <- factor(propho$session, levels = c("immediate","delayed")`) , I come to you in hope of finding an answer.

Thank you all in advance for any insights you could share with me.

Comment: Hi @asderad, could you please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: @Quinten, thank you for your reply. As the "dput" output exceeds my console backlog, it seems too exhaustive to post it here as is. Can I give you another precision to help you help me ?

Comment: @jdobres, and thank you too. I've seen the reorder command suggested but am unsure how to implement it into my ggplot. In the "reorder(Position,Position, function(x)-length(x)" structure what do the individual terms correspond to in my case ?

Comment: You could share a sample of your data using head(dput(), 20)?

Comment: @Quinten; There you go, a sample of the initial dataframe and the dataframe used to create the ggplot (knowing that I've followed this tutorial in order to adapt results of a mixed model : https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/08/plotting-mixed-effects-model-results-with-effects-package/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `factor` with `ordered = T` to change the way that **ggplot** interprets the ordering. Your original plotting code can remain the same:

```
propho.effect.frame$session <- factor(propho.effect.frame$session, c('immediate', 'delayed'), ordered = T)

ggplot(propho.effect.frame, aes(session, fit, color=modality, fill=modality)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position="dodge") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se), width=0.4, position=position_dodge(width=0.9)) + 
  theme_bw(base_size=12) + labs(y="score", title="Phonological Production Task")
```

[image]

Comment: You sir are a godsend, my deepest gratitude for your insight;
That did the trick perfectly. 

I completely overlooked the fact that I have to change the order for the dataframe that's actually specified in the ggplot - I falsely assumed that changing the order in the initial dataframe was sufficient. 

Thanks a million and have a very nice evening !